# Can all files be removed in the user's bash session directory?

Tags: terminal, bash, history

I didn't see this question asked or could find any answers when I Googled but I thought `history -c` would clear all my Bash history but there are still several files in .bash_sessions located under `/Users/user/.bash_sessions`.

What is the difference between these files and the bash history file of *.bash_history*? Can the files in this directory (`/.bash_sessions`) be deleted safely? There are over 200 files with random letters, numbers and dashes followed by the extensions of .historynew, .history and .session.

Answer (score 2):

A session file is commands from a single session.

The history is an incomplete collection of commands used in any session.

I don't know for sure whether anything (other than loss of history) would occur from deleting them, but I suspect not.  An easy test would be move them all to another directory, then move them back if you see a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not need the *shell session history information* stored for any reason, then to stop the `.history` and `.historynew` *files* from being created, you can add `SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0` to your `~/.bash_profile`*file* or `~/.bashrc` *file* and restart **Terminal** and it will stop creating those *files*.

If you do not want the `.session` *files*, then in your `$HOME` *directory* use `touch .bash_sessions_disable`. However I would do that and just clean out the `.bash_sessions` *directory* once in a while.

Yes, it's safe to delete the file in the `.bash_sessions` *directory*.